# What's the the integral of $\tan(e^x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The integral of tangent is $\ln(\sec(x))$ so I was thinking that the answer is $\ln(\sec(e^x))$ but the derivative of that is $e^x\ln(\sec(x))$ so that would not be the correct answer. So what is the integral of $\tan(e^x)$?

Comment: There is no closed form ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+tan%28e%5Ex%29)). Many integrals do not have closed forms, and even if a similar looking integral has a closed form, that doesn't guarantee a closed form for the original integral.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that?

Comment: It is very difficult to prove that no closed form exists. However, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral) are some possible strategies that people use to prove this.